# child_process cant execute docker run

Tags: docker, electron

Using simple commands like ls, pwd and even open an external application I have success using child process, but when using exec with a docker command in a built electron app, I get this error:

```
exec Error: Command failed: docker exec -it 6bec55e9e86e touch home.html
the input device is not a TTY
```

Here is the code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('docker exec -it 6bec55e9e86e touch casa.html', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
  console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
  if (error !== null) {
    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

please remove `-t` flag. so you command should be `docker exec -i 6bec55e9e86e touch casa.html`.

this error `the input device is not a TTY` mean your input device is not a Teletypes(terminal), and in the commands of docker, `-t` flag symbols a `terminal`, so they are conflict. so just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `spawn` and set `options.stdio` to `inherit` will work:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn('docker', ['exec', '-it', '6bec55e9e86e', 'touch', 'casa.html'], { stdio: 'inherit' })
```