# NodeJS exec with Docker – the input device is not a TTY

Tags: node.js, child-process

I wrote a script that let the user choose the command that will be executed in shell.
For that I used `child-process-promise` library – a code for running a command can be simplified to this:

```
import Process from 'child-process-promise';

const test = async () => {
  await Process.exec('docker run --rm --tty --interactive ...');
};

test();
```

All would be okay, but I'm getting `stderr` like:

```
the input device is not a TTY\nmake: *** [display_status] Error 1\n
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40758960/3049705) removing the `-t`/`--tty` flag should resolve the issue.